Identical Selections
I have several vconcat plots that all share an x-axis. As I have a helpful label assigned to each selection, I would like the selection to be shared by all plots. That is, if I create a selection on any plot, that selection should appear on all plots. If I remove a selection from any plot, it should be removed from all plots.
At no time should the selections differ.
This is similar to my previous question Synchronized Selections except that now I would like for the selections to be identical across all vconcat plots. The selection of each plot is tied to the x encoding; no selection is bound to the plot scales.
For example:


Thank you for the edit, much appreciated. I've voted to reopen it. Give it some time; reopening is a slow process.

As with the answer to the linked question, I am starting from Overview and Detail example on vega-lite's site, using the v5 schema. The steps:

For every layer, patch the generated Vega to push the s1_x signal to the outer scope.

Patch the brush visuals to use the appropriate row from the now multi-row s1_store table.


vlSpec = {
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vega/vega-datasets/main/data/sp500.csv"},
  "vconcat": [
    { 
      "params": [
        { "name": "s1",
          "select":
            { "type": "interval",
              "encodings": ["x"]
            }
        }
      ],
      "width": 480,
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "date",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {"title": ""}
        },
        "y": {"field": "price", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "params": [
        { "name": "s1",
          "select":
            { "type": "interval",
              "encodings": ["x"]
            }
        }
      ],
      "width": 480,
      "height": 60,
      "mark": "area",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {
          "field": "price",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "axis": {"tickCount": 3, "grid": false}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
vegaEmbed( '#vis', vlSpec, {"patch": spec => {
spec.signals.push({"name": "s1_x", "value": []});
  for (const [idx, group] of spec.marks.entries()) {
    let s1_x = group.signals.find(i => i.name == "s1_x")
    delete s1_x.value
    s1_x.push = "outer"
    for (const mark of group.marks) {
      if (!mark.name.startsWith("s1_brush")) {
        continue
      }
      console.log("mark: ", mark)
      for (const set of Object.values(mark.encode.update)) {
        for (const prop of set) {
          if (!Object.hasOwn(prop, "test")) {
            continue
          }
          console.log("found one", prop)
          prop.test = prop.test.replace("[0].unit ", `[${idx}].unit `)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return spec
}}).then(function(result) {
}).catch(console.error);

